# Covering a CALayer with a CGImage

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, appkit, cgimage

I have a `CGImage` that I want to show in a `CALayer`. Setting the content and the gravity to the bottom-left works like expected.

```
layer.contents = cgimage
layer.contentsGravity = .bottomLeft
```

[image]

Now I want center and cover the full layer. Using `.center` just shifts the content center to the bottom-left.

```
layer.contents = cgimage
layer.contentsGravity = .center
```

[image]

Only when I set the position to the center of the view it displays as expected.

```
layer.contents = cgimage
layer.contentsGravity = .center
layer.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2)
```

[image]

But with gravity set to resize-aspect-fill nothing is shown at all - with the position set or not.

```
layer.contents = cgimage
layer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

I have the feeling that I missing something fundamental.

Why isn't the `CGImage` in the `CALayer` covering the full size and keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: You are not showing your real code. Show it. Where is the part where you set the layer's frame? Or the layer's bounds and position? Where is the part where you put the layer into the interface? How do you generate the image? Give all details needed to _reproduce_ the phenomena. Show your code if you want help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out for a `contentGravity` of type `.resize` and `.resizeAspectFill` the frame of a `CALayer` has to be explicitly set. For a `.center` or `.bottomLeft` you can get away without.

Answer (score 0):

I can show image fill. I think ur calyer of view is not center in parent view.

```
    let view = UIView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(view)
    view.layer.contents = UIImage.init(named:"ic_control_group_unselect_on")?.cgImage
    view.layer.contentsGravity = .resize
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that doesn't seem to be the case. (0,0) is at the bottom-left. PS: be aware this is about AppKit not UIKit - although they are very similar.